# Are there libraries to perform xslt transformation in erlang?

Tags: xml, xslt, erlang

I'm really new to erlang and I'm wondering how to manipulate xml.

I've found [erlsom](http://sourceforge.net/projects/erlsom) but I need to do some simple transformation on a xml.

I'm looking for an xslt (even 1.0) library, but I haven't found anything and reduced myself to do the transformations by hand working on the DOM, or whatever you can call a structure representing the xml-tree in erlang.
No need to say that the result is an unelegant mess of code that I use to obtain a result i can achieve with an xslt of a bunch of lines.

Do you know code library, or examples, or documentation that can point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://erlang.org/doc/apps/xmerl/xmerl_xs_examples.html

[http://erlang.org/user.html#sablotron-1.0 - via WayBackMachine - scroll down the page a bit](http://web.archive.org/web/20101123100410/http://erlang.org/user.html#sablotron-1.0)

https://github.com/hyperthunk/erlxsl